# PyOpt installation causes undefined reference to `__intrinsic_setjmpex'

Tags: python, windows, compiler-errors, installation, gfortran

I am trying to install the optimization library pyOpt on Windows 7 (64-bit - Python 3.6) following the instructions on [PyOpt\Installing](http://www.pyopt.org/install.html).

I have installed the required dependencies but I get the following error:

```
compiling C sources
C compiler: gcc -g -DDEBUG -DMS_WIN64 -O0 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes

compile options: '-DNPY_MINGW_USE_CUSTOM_MSVCR -D__MSVCRT_VERSION__=0x1900 -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.6\build\src.win-amd64-3.6\pyALGENCAN\source\f2py -IC:\Users\gporzio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Users\gporzio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\include -IC:\Users\gporzio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\include -c'
gcc -g -DDEBUG -DMS_WIN64 -O0 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DNPY_MINGW_USE_CUSTOM_MSVCR -D__MSVCRT_VERSION__=0x1900 -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.6\build\src.win-amd64-3.6\pyALGENCAN\source\f2py -IC:\Users\gporzio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Users\gporzio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\include -IC:\Users\gporzio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\include -c build\src.win-amd64-3.6\pyALGENCAN\source\f2py\algencanmodule.c -o build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\build\src.win-amd64-3.6\pyalgencan\source\f2py\algencanmodule.o
gcc -g -DDEBUG -DMS_WIN64 -O0 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DNPY_MINGW_USE_CUSTOM_MSVCR -D__MSVCRT_VERSION__=0x1900 -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.6\build\src.win-amd64-3.6\pyALGENCAN\source\f2py -IC:\Users\gporzio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Users\gporzio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\include -IC:\Users\gporzio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\include -c build\src.win-amd64-3.6\build\src.win-amd64-3.6\pyALGENCAN\source\f2py\fortranobject.c -o build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\build\src.win-amd64-3.6\build\src.win-amd64-3.6\pyalgencan\source\f2py\fortranobject.o
compiling Fortran sources
Fortran f77 compiler: C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-7.3.0-win32-seh-rt_v5-rev0\mingw64\bin\gfortran.exe -Wall -g -ffixed-form -fno-second-underscore -O3 -funroll-loops
Fortran f90 compiler: C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-7.3.0-win32-seh-rt_v5-rev0\mingw64\bin\gfortran.exe -Wall -g -fno-second-underscore -O3 -funroll-loops
Fortran fix compiler: C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-7.3.0-win32-seh-rt_v5-rev0\mingw64\bin\gfortran.exe -Wall -g -ffixed-form -fno-second-underscore -Wall -g -fno-second-underscore -O3 -funroll-loops
compile options: '-Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.6\build\src.win-amd64-3.6\pyALGENCAN\source\f2py -IC:\Users\gporzio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Users\gporzio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\include -IC:\Users\gporzio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\include -c'
gfortran.exe:f77: build\src.win-amd64-3.6\pyALGENCAN\source\f2py\algencan-f2pywrappers.f
C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-7.3.0-win32-seh-rt_v5-rev0\mingw64\bin\gfortran.exe -Wall -g -Wall -g -shared build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\build\src.win-amd64-3.6\pyalgencan\source\f2py\algencanmodule.o build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\build\src.win-amd64-3.6\build\src.win-amd64-3.6\pyalgencan\source\f2py\fortranobject.o build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\build\src.win-amd64-3.6\pyALGENCAN\source\f2py\algencan-f2pywrappers.o -L"C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-7.3.0-win32-seh-rt_v5-rev0\mingw64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\7.3.0" -LC:\Users\gporzio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\libs -LC:\Users\gporzio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\PCbuild\amd64 -Lbuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6 -lalgencan -lpython36 -lgfortran -o build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\pyOpt\pyALGENCAN\algencan.cp36-win_amd6
4.pyd
build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\build\src.win-amd64-3.6\pyalgencan\source\f2py\algencanmodule.o: In function `f2py_rout_algencan_algencan':
C:\Users\gporzio\Desktop\pyOpt-1.2.0\pyOpt/build/src.win-amd64-3.6/pyALGENCAN/source/f2py/algencanmodule.c:3397: undefined reference to `__intrinsic_setjmpex'
C:\Users\gporzio\Desktop\pyOpt-1.2.0\pyOpt/build/src.win-amd64-3.6/pyALGENCAN/source/f2py/algencanmodule.c:3397: undefined reference to `__intrinsic_setjmpex'
C:\Users\gporzio\Desktop\pyOpt-1.2.0\pyOpt/build/src.win-amd64-3.6/pyALGENCAN/source/f2py/algencanmodule.c:3397: undefined reference to `__intrinsic_setjmpex'
C:\Users\gporzio\Desktop\pyOpt-1.2.0\pyOpt/build/src.win-amd64-3.6/pyALGENCAN/source/f2py/algencanmodule.c:3397: undefined reference to `__intrinsic_setjmpex'
C:\Users\gporzio\Desktop\pyOpt-1.2.0\pyOpt/build/src.win-amd64-3.6/pyALGENCAN/source/f2py/algencanmodule.c:3397: undefined reference to `__intrinsic_setjmpex'
build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\build\src.win-amd64-3.6\pyalgencan\source\f2py\algencanmodule.o:C:\Users\gporzio\Desktop\pyOpt-1.2.0\pyOpt/build/src.win-amd64-3.6/pyALGENCAN/source/f2py/algencanmodule.c:3397: more undefined references to `__intrinsic_setjmpex' follow
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: Command "C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-7.3.0-win32-seh-rt_v5-rev0\mingw64\bin\gfortran.exe -Wall -g -Wall -g -shared build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\build\src.win-amd64-3.6\pyalgencan\source\f2py\algencanmodule.o build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\build\src.win-amd64-3.6\build\src.win-amd64-3.6\pyalgencan\source\f2py\fortranobject.o build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\build\src.win-amd64-3.6\pyALGENCAN\source\f2py\algencan-f2pywrappers.o -L"C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-7.3.0-win32-seh-rt_v5-rev0\mingw64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\7.3.0" -LC:\Users\gporzio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\libs -LC:\Users\gporzio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\PCbuild\amd64 -Lbuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6 -lalgencan -lpython36 -lgfortran -o build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\pyOpt\pyALGENCAN\algenc
an.cp36-win_amd64.pyd" failed with exit status 1
```

I've tried both with `python setup.py install` and with python `setup.py build --compiler=mingw32` but I always get the same error.
Could someone give me some suggestion?